# How can I analyze Java 8 code using latest SonarQube free edition that uses Java 11?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have installed latest version of SonarQube using Java 11 pointed from its config i.e. `wrapper.config`. I have read that it can analyze code even written in Java 8, but I am getting following exception:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar
> (default-cli) on project ptf-parent: Execution default-cli of goal
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar
> failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar:
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled
> by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
> 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Currently, my code is build using Java 8 and I want to analyze using the latest SonarQube version.

I am running analyzer from Eclipse IDE. All my projects are configured to use Java 8 and Maven 3.8.2 to use sonar parameters to push report on SonarQube, but it does not work.

Below are the parameters I am providing in Eclipse Run as Maven build:

```
 -e clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.java.jdkHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251 -Dsonar.project
-Dsonar.projectKey=TESTPROJECT -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=a2603f6cd079e4a7833179333333333333333333e
```

Comment: You can have a different java version for the project, by providing the proper java home following the docs: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/

Comment: i have made java_home to JDK 11 but does not work.

Comment: You have to read the _Project's specific JDK_ paragraph and set the `sonar.java.jdkHome` to the Java 8 JDK installation, if your project use Java 8.

Comment: check my edited question above, In maven params while running from eclipse i am providing it. but it remains same. Let me know if i am missing some thing.

Comment: I see now you're using Maven, the documentation tell that in this case you don't have to set nothing. If the project is properly configured and build with Maven in Java 8, you just need to run the plugin. And remove the configuration.

Comment: that does not work for me. i can remove jdkHome parameter and still the result is same. do i have to set some thing in POM ?

Comment: You should have already set the Java version on the pom file _maven.compiler.target_ and _maven.compiler.source_ in the properties section.

Answer (score 0):

According to [sonarqube community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/upgrading-to-7-9-version-sonarqube-requires-java-11-to-run/14836), you should try the following:

Edit `conf\wrapper.conf`, specifically the `wrapper.java.command` to following:

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\open jdk-11.0.2\bin\java 
#wrapper.java.command=java
```