# SonarQube 9.8 needs Java 11 but java application are still using Java 8 (warpper.conf is missing)

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I am upgrading SonarQube from 8.9 to 9.8 using ZIP and it does not contain wrapper.conf file and has only sonar.properties file.
`{sonar_home}\conf\wrapper.conf`
I am using Azure pipelines for code scan after the build task is successful.

My problem is the machines (Azure self-hosted agents) on which the scan is running have default JAVA_HOME set to java8 because applications still use java8. (Java11 is also setup but not set as default)
And while scanning (with the help of azure task SonarQubeAnalyze@4) I get the below error

```
##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
##[error]java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

How can I solve this problem without doing extra configuration at the application side?
I was thinking to add the below configuration in wrapper.conf file but SonarQube 9.8 ZIP does not come with this wrapper.conf file.
`wrapper.java.command={…java11 path}`

For reference: [How can I analyze Java 8 code using latest SonarQube free edition that uses Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281549/how-can-i-analyze-java-8-code-using-latest-sonarqube-free-edition-that-uses-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting java env using the 'env: {JAVA_PATH}' at task level

```
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: How did u set this up? I tried this: task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5 env: {JAVA_HOME} and still the error persists

Comment: Please see the above Ans I edited it with code snippet, It should work for you please verify & confirm

Answer (score 0):

Add the required Java version with `JavaToolInstaller@0` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/java-tool-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines):

```
      - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '21'
          jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
          jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
```

And then configure the `SonarQubeAnalyze@5` task to use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sonar-qube-analyze-v5?view=azure-pipelines).

```
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
  inputs:
    jdkversion: 'JAVA_HOME'
```